# Android: Loading JavaScript with WebView.loadUrl but keeping soft keyboard

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

When a user click on a (html) `Textfield` in a `WebView`, the soft keyboard is shown.
But when I load some JS with `WebView.loadUrl()` the soft keyboard disappears.

I understand the behaviour when you load a new page. But how can I change the behaviour of the `WebView` when loading JS?

Is there another way to load JS?

I also tried to handle the keyboard manually. But there are too many drawbacks.
It is complicated to determine if the keyboard is shown. And I would have to change my layout:
[How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/android-is-software-keyboard-shown)

And the keyboard would not be in the control of the `WebView` anymore.

Q: How to load JS into a WebView, without affecting the soft keyboard?

Answer (score -1):

After loading javascript give focus to textfield again. That will solve problem. For giving focus [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080579/android-textfield-set-focus-soft-input-programmatically) discussion will be helpful.

Enjoy :)