# Android TextField : set focus + soft input programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my view, I have a search EditText and I would like to trigger programmatically the behaviour of a click event on the field, i.e give focus to the text field AND display soft keyboard if necessary (if no hard keyboard available).

I tried `field.requestFocus()`. The field actually gets focus but soft keyboard is not displayed.

I tried `field.performClick()`. But that only calls the OnClickListener of the field.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Good sir, try this:

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
edittext.requestFocus();
```

I'm not sure, but this might be required on some phones (some of the older devices):

```
final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: Same result as requestFocus() alone... Field gets focus but the soft keyboard is not triggered.

Comment: I finally solved the issued by calling `field.requestFocus()` in the `onResume()` method of the activity (instead of the `onCreate()`).
Don't exactly know why it works...

Comment: A view cannot take focus before it actually has been laid out on the screen. This cannot be done while onCreate() holds the UI-thread, therefore the view is laid out directly after onCreate() and before onResume(). :)

Comment: @fiddler It works in `onResume` because `onResume` is called after `onCreate`, so `field` doesn't exist until `onCreate` is run. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: thnx man .. giving focus to the edit text in onResume method works for me.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, ol' chap. I do declare; this is well deserving of an upvote!

Comment: @pgsandstrom but in my app the soft keyboard is not triggered too. I use fragment and call this in onViewCreated methode!

Answer (score 66):

Here is the code that worked for me.

```
edittext.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        edittext.requestFocusFromTouch();
        InputMethodManager lManager = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
        lManager.showSoftInput(edittext, 0);
    }
});
```

That's it! Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks and this one worked for me. I add `EditText` programmatically when user hits button.

Comment: I added an `EditText` from a dialog modal.  Some flags are getting set by Android that cause this control to not receive any touches.  If you add the field in the runnable, the flags don't get set.

Comment: It looks like the `InputType` of the `EditText` is being set to null by Android.  If you set the `InputType`, it should work.

Comment: The only working solution for me (if I use InputMethodManager to show keyboard forced, then I can't hide it)

Comment: None of the other methods worked for me, but this one did. I wanted to have a box for users to click in to open the edit dialogue view instead of having an edit line to click for an EditText view. On a phone the edit line loses most of it's functionality as the edit dialogue view covers then entire screen, so the user can't see the edit line, including the letters going in it while they are typing, anyway.

Answer (score 7):

The *following code* **worked for me**, after the *other two answers* **didn't work for me**:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().register(this);
    //passwordInput.requestFocus(); <-- that doesn't work
    passwordInput.postDelayed(new ShowKeyboard(), 300); //250 sometimes doesn't run if returning from LockScreen
}
```

Where `ShowKeyboard` is

```
private class ShowKeyboard implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        passwordInput.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
  //      passwordInput.requestFocusFromTouch();
        passwordInput.requestFocus();            
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        ((InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(passwordInput, 0);
    }
}
```

After a successful input, I also make sure I hide the keyboard

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
((InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                    .hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Technically, I just added 300 ms of delay before running the soft keyboard display request. Weird, right? Also changed `requestFocus()` to `requestFocusFromTouch()`.

EDIT: Don't use `requestFocusFromTouch()` it gives a touch event to the launcher. Stick with `requestFocus()`.

EDIT2: In Dialogs (`DialogFragment`), use the following

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

instead of

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: `requestFocusFromTouch()` seems to trigger a touch event on the launcher. This is weird.

Comment: For hiding the keyboard, does the ((InputMethodManager) getActivity()..." code line also need to change for use in a DialogFragment or is the code line you mention above sufficient?

Comment: It should most likely work but you can always try it and see

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I wanted to display the virtual keyboard with no reference to a specific textbox, so I used the first part of the accepted answer to **focus** :

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
edittext.requestFocus();
```

Then I show the **virtual keyboard** :

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

for kotlin, implement using extension function as follow

```kotlin
fun View.showSoftKeyboard() {
    this.requestFocus()
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        field.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                field.requestFocus();
                field.onKeyUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case just this solved all problems:

```
val inputMethodManager: InputMethodManager = 
   context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
```

I have put it in RecyclerView Adapter, because I use data binding.
Also I haven't used `edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` because in my layout it is `true` by default.
And don't use this line: `edittext.requestFocus()`. When I removed it, it started to work :)

Answer (score 0):

val  mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()

```
        //Coloca o foo no txtDlgQuantidade e então chama o teclado
        mDialogView.txtDlgQuantidade.isFocusable = true
        mDialogView.txtDlgQuantidade.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        mDialogView.txtDlgQuantidade.requestFocus()
        mAlertDialog.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM)
        mAlertDialog.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)
```